# asp.net mvc How can I show GivenName and Surname instead of Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I have a project that authenticates a user against LDAP Active Directory and restrict access to certain views based on Membership. Most of the work is done in a class `/Models/AdAuthenticationService.cs` Everything works fine so far; however, I can't seem to be able to show user parameters like GivenName and Surname in the _Layout.cshtml

My AdAuthenticationService class has the following:

```c#
namespace MyFDM.Models {
  public class AdAuthenticationService {


    private ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
      var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userPrincipal.GivenName));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, userPrincipal.Surname));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipal.EmailAddress)) {
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userPrincipal.EmailAddress));
      }
```

And my _LoginPartial.cshtml contains:

```html
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello @User.Identity.Name!<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

I can assign any of the Identity attributes to Name; for example:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.DisplayName));
```

And this would display the correct user name instead of the SamAccountName; But what I really need to do is show GivenName + Surname like:

```html
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello @User.Identity.GivenName + @User.Identity.Surname!<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

But if I do this, I get the following Error:
Error   CS1061  'IIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'GivenName' and no extension method 'GivenName' accepting a first argument of type 'IIdentity' could be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but the way I did this was to create a method in a helper class that returned a UserPrincipal (make sure it doesn't return a Principal or not all properties will be present).  Like this:

```
public class ADServices {
        PrincipalContext prinContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ad");

        public UserPrincipal GetUser(string userName) {
            UserPrincipal userPrin = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(prinContext, userName);

            if (userPrin == null) {
                throw new Exception("The username " + userName + " does not exist.");
            }

        return userPrin;
    }
}
```

This provided all of the properties that you can find detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.givenname(v=vs.110).aspx) to my controller, where I simply applied it to a ViewBag.UserName

```
   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
        ADServices ads = new ADServices();
        var userPrin = ads.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.UserName = userPrin.GivenName + " " + userPrin.Surname;
        ...(other code omitted)
        return View(model);
    }
```

and used that on my View:

```
<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @ViewBag.UserName!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this post before, and tried it. But it did not work for me. I kept getting an exception that the domain or LDAP could not be found.